# Java 7 u45 broken Spring context loading

Tags: spring, java-7, java-web-start

Spring loads its context resolvers using ClassLoader.getResources("META-INF/spring.handlers"), but the latest release of JRE 7 u45 seems not to return all of the actual resources with that name, only one is returned.
All the original Spring JARs have been manipulated by adding extra attributes to the Manifest (Permission:all-permission and Trusted-Library:true), but this seems not to affect the result (also, I'm wondering why the first JAR in the classpath is returned, instead).

The context file(s) are correct since the launch from CLI (in lab env) works fine. WebStart launch is broken since we've updated the JRE.

Apart from finding out an alternative to Java WebStart, which is probably the next step, is there any reasonable work-around to that?

```
...
Error while intializing Spring Application Context -
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location 
...
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
...
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
```

Comment: I think you can specify the desired jre in your deployment descriptor.

Comment: this means users cannot install the latest JRE? I fear they will never accept this limitation